# How to print 2 smallest numbers from unknown count of numbers

Tags: c

I need help in writing a code in C

I need to write a code that get unknown numbers from the user (up to `INT_MAX`) and print the two smallest numbers from them.

Can anyone help me with the code? searched for about an hour on-line.

The best I've got so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void main()
{
    int num, min1 = INT_MAX, min2 = INT_MAX;
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;

    printf("Plese enter your numbers:\n");

    do
    {
        scanf("%d\n", &num);
        temp1 = num;
        temp2 = num;

        if ((temp1 < min1) && (temp1 > 0));
        {
            min1 = num;
        }

        if ((temp2 < min2) && (temp2 > 0))
        {
            min2 = temp2;
        }

    } while (num != 0);

    printf("%-5d%5d\n\n", min1, min2);
}
```

Comment: Note: Better to add a space between number.  ---> `printf("%-5d %5d\n\n", min1, min2);`, else 11111, 22222 will print as 1111122222.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m1, m2, num;
    m1 = m2 = INT_MAX;
    while(scanf("%d", &num) == 1)
    {
        if(num < m1)
        {
            m2 = m1;
            m1 = num;
        }
        else if(num < m2)
        {
            m2 = num;
        }
    }
    printf("%d and %d\n", m1, m2);
    return 0;
}
```

`scanf("%d", &num);` reads an int and returns the number of successful arguments read. So as long as it reads an int, it will continue looping. To exit the loop, you can enter `^X` (EOF) in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment!, iv'e been asked to use the do while loop for this program and that the user will enter as much numbers as he wants until he enter zero.

Comment: Sure. Just a question: Does the exit condition must be the number being equal to 0?

Comment: Cut the `while(scanf("%d", &num) == 1)`, replace it with a `do`, paste after the closing brace, add a `';'`, and add an `if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) return 1; before the `do`.

Comment: If it's homework (I assume it is because of the `do... while` requirement), the professor probably won't be happy with a return inside a loop.
You can also put a `scanf()` before the `do` and another `scanf()` in the `while` condition, along with `&& num != 0`.

Comment: Yeh.. iv'e managed to to change your code to my requirement, can't belive it was so simple after hours of trying.. but i learned from it so it's ok after all.